# Topology and algebraic topology have any application in biology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, education, math-history

If so,

In what area? evolution, genetecs ....

And how good do my computer skills need to be to work in these areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topology and knot theory are used to study DNA supercoiling and topoisomerases in molecular biology. There is a little elaboration in *The Knot Book* by Colin Adams. See also, for example, http://www.omup.jp/modules/papers/knot/chap17.pdf.

Rational [tangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangle_(mathematics)) calculus also has applications to the analysis of DNA recombination. See the last section of this: [http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/RTang.pdf](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ekauffman/RTang.pdf).